# Is it Possible to Preserve Local Z-Axis Rotation Relative to Surface Normal while Snapping to Face?

Tags: snapping

The Transform (grab) with Snap-to-Face (and Align-Rotation-to-Target enabled) feature has an 'unintuitive' local-z-rotation relative to target face, IMO. I am not sure if this z-rotation happens due to user-error (unapplied transforms, unchecked boxes, etc.) or some mathematical unavoidability. I tried various settings to no avail.

Before snap-transform:

[image]

After snap-transform (with unintuitive local-z-rotation):

[image]

Before performing the snapped transformation, I moved the cube origin to a face (to align cube surface rather than cube center):

[image]

Then checked the target face normal makes sense (they look similar, though offset a bit):

[image]

Showing the issue from another angle, the following two images are snap transformation start and end positions. The cube local z-rotation changes ~45 degrees relative to the start and end surface normals. If the algorithm is "intended" then in what scenario is that 45 degree local-z-rotation useful? I expect the object local orientation to match the target surface normal orientation when "Snap to Face" and "Align Rotation to Target" are selected.

[image]

[image]

Am I misunderstanding snap alignment or missing an option somewhere?